# Bugs when use app-dir-i18n-routing of Next.js example

Tags: internationalization, syntax-error, typeerror, vercel, next.js13

When i execute npx create-next-app --example app-dir-i18n-routing i18n-app then run the code in my device, I always get this error when running on my device although when running on other devices it is normal.

[image]

I don't know why. Please help me.